# Trying to get the number of entries between certain dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In regards to the screen shots below, I am trying to make a formula that will give me the number of times QLD appears per month's data.

**Raw Data**
[image]

Table Data
[image]

The second screenshot gives what I thought would work. But it just comes back with 0 instead of 4. Here's the code if people find this to work with.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(Sheet1!C2:C500<=Sheet1!O2),--(Sheet1!C2:C500>=Sheet1!N2),--(Sheet1!B2:B500="QLD"))`

What am I doing wrong? I have been Googling like mad but I can't quite make it work.

Also, if anyone has a hint for me to be able to total the value of QLD entries per month that would also be appreciated. (i.e. January QLD total value would be $1,275,000)

Thanks in advance! Please let me know if anything needs clarifying.

Comment: Is the data in column C stored as dates, or as text?  I noticed 6 Feb isn't formatted as the other ones are, so that's enough to make me suspicious.  (It could simply be that it has been formatted differently.)

Comment: Assuming you have dates in column C, you can use `=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!C2:C500,">="&Sheet1!N2,Sheet1!C2:C500,"<="&Sheet1!O2,Sheet1!B2:B500,"QLD")` for the count, and `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!D2:D500,Sheet1!C2:C500,">="&Sheet1!N2,Sheet1!C2:C500,"<="&Sheet1!O2,Sheet1!B2:B500,"QLD")` for the sum.